# How to check and count if value of dataframe one exist in other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, countif

I have 2 dataframes, added with pd.read_csv. I create dataframe like this:

```
df1= pd.read_csv('exo.csv', delimiter=';', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

the 2 datafames are:`

```
df1:
    date     number
  jan-16 
  feb-17
  march-17 
  april-17

Df2:
   date     
  09/01/2016
  08/02/2017
  15/02/2017
  13/03/2017 
  25/08/2017
```

I would like to **check if value of df1.date exists in df2.value**. If yes, the column df1['number'] will count the number of appearance. The result of Df1 should then be like this:

```
date     number
jan-16     1
feb-17     2  (=> for instance, feb-17 has found 2 times in Df2['date'])
```

How can i do this ? do I need to change the date format ?

I thank you in advance,

Comment: feb-16 does not appear twice in the 2nd data frame, feb-17 is.

Answer (score 0):

you need to group by df2.date and then count [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9hwF.png)
than you can merge df df2 to df1 by 'date1'

```
df2['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
df2['date1'] = df2.date2.dt.strftime('%b-%y').astype(str).str.lower()
b = pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby('date1')['date'].count())
b.columns = ['number']
b = b.reset_index()
```

then merge

```
df1['date']=df1.date.str.lower()
df1.merge(b,right_on='date1' , left_on='date',how='left')
```